# Python: Finding Start/End Date Based on Duration, Work Week Length, and One Date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to fill in some bad data.
Sometimes there is a Start Date and no End Date and sometimes there is an End Date and no Start Date, but the table gives the Duration (in days) of the task and the Work Week Length.

(Note: Work Week Length is 5 day (excludes weekends), 6 day (excludes Sunday), and 7 day.)

[Example of the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jbc5.png)

How would I go about this?
I've calculated unknown Durations already with Start/End Dates and Work Week Length, but am unsure how to go about doing things a little backwards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timedelta` function of the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module to help you.

You can calculate the number of days by working out the full weeks (7 per week) + any additional days worked after accounting for the weeks.

Here is an example:

```
import datetime

# sample data
start_date = "07/01/2022"
duration = 6
work_week = 5

# calculate the days to add (full weeks + left over days)
days = (7 * (duration // work_week)) + (duration % work_week)

# add the days to the start date
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%Y") + datetime.timedelta(days=days)

# display the result
print(end_date)
```

If you have an end date and wish to find the start date then the code is similar to the above except you subtract the number of days from the end date:

```
# subtract the days from the end date
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%d/%m/%Y") - datetime.timedelta(days=days)
```

You can adapt the above examples to work with your database. It may be useful to create a suitable function that you can call as shown below:

```
def calculate_date(date, duration, work_week, is_end_date=False):
    
  # calculate the weeks
  weeks = (7 * (duration // work_week))
  
  # calculate remaining work days
  remaining_days = (duration % work_week)
  
  # calculate total actual days
  days = weeks + remaining_days
  
  # determine date
  current = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
  
  if is_end_date:
    result = current - datetime.timedelta(days=days)
  else:
    result = current + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
  
  return result
```